# Pulling xslt:text from xml file as text for a clickable link

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

So I'm trying to create a sitmap with xml and an xslt files.

I want the URL's for the sitemap to be clickable when displayed (VERY new to this)... here is as far as I got:

```
<h3>Sitemap</h3>
<xsl:for-each select="urlset/url">
<p>
    <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="loc"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:text>Link</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
</p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

any know how to change the word "Link" to be the URL of the site address its directing to? whilst still keeping the hyperlink in there?

I have already tried:

```
<h3>Sitemap</h3>
<xsl:for-each select="urlset/url">
<p>
    <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="loc"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="loc"/></xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
</p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I get an error :(

HELP?

Comment: What is your XSLT processor (Xalan, Saxon)? And what is your error?

Answer (score 1):

The `<xsl:text>` element [cannot have any child elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256107.aspx). Try removing the `<xsl:text>` element from around `<xsl:value-of select="loc"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the extra-`<xsl:text>` tag as [`<xsl:value>` will already create a text node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of) :

> The xsl:value-of element is instantiated to create a text node in the result tree.

Moreover, as [@eero-helenius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889915/802365) already stated `<xsl:text>` doesn't accept child elements.